# XCUIElement Textfield Custom class

Tags: objective-c, xcode-ui-testing, uiaccessibility

So I have a custom UITextField that also has a floating label (using JVFloatLabeledTextField) that is in a custom view. In my custom view class I set the accessibility element to the JVFloatLabelTextField  like so

```js
CustomView.h

   
   self.textField.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.textField.floatingLabel.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
//  CGRect textFieldFrame = self.textField.frame - self.textField.floatingLabel.frame;
    CGRect textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.textField.floatingLabel.frame.size.height, self.textField.frame.size.width, self.textField.frame.size.height - self.textField.floatingLabel.frame.size.height);
    textFieldElement.accessibilityFrame = [self convertRect:textFieldFrame toView:nil];
    textFieldElement.accessibilityIdentifier = @"TextField";
    textFieldElement.accessibilityLabel = @"text field";
    [self.accessibleElements addObject:textFieldElement];
```

In my UI Test class, I created a test to find the text field and it crashes on typeText. For some reason, it is not recognizing the textfield as a of XCUIElement type text field, instead it recognizes it as type other. Here I check if the element exists:

This element does NOT exist

```js
    XCUIElement *textFieldElement = [[scrollViewQuery.otherElements matchingIdentifier:@"CustomView"] containingType:XCUIElementTypeTextField identifier:@"TextField"].element;
```

But this DOES exist:

```js
XCUIElement *textFieldName = [scrollViewQuery.otherElements matchingIdentifier:@"CustomView"].otherElements[@"TextField"];
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to recognize the textfield as of XCUIElement type textfield??? Thank you!

Comment: Why does it matter? You can still call `typeText:` on any `XCUIElement`, text field or not.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti because it fails everytime I use typeText. I have turned off connect hardware keyboard and it still fails. I've narrowed it down to failing at that specific line. I see the keyboard, but right when it tries to type it fails

Comment: Does the element have focus? You can inspect this with `Accessibility Inspector.app` on your Mac.

Comment: Try adding the '[adjustable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraitadjustable)' accessibility trait to the view.